# Mann Kendall test on snow cover images in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I am trying perform Mann Kendall test in Google Earth Engine, but output show zero image. I am attaching the code link. https://code.earthengine.google.com/a6dd42809be0452450990cec70de71b0

```
dataset = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD09A1')
              .filter(ee.Filter.date('2001-01-01', '2002-12-31'))
              .map(function(img) {return img.clip(table)});


var cloud_free = dataset.map(  
  function(img) { 
  var qa = img.select('StateQA')
  var cloudState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 1) 
  var cloudShadowState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 2)
  var cirrusState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8, 9)
  var mask = cloudState.eq(0) // Clear
  .and(cloudShadowState.eq(0)) // No cloud shadow
  .and(cirrusState.eq(0)) // No cirrus


  var maskedImage = img.updateMask(mask);
  return maskedImage.addBands(mask.rename('mask'));
  })

 function bitwiseExtract(value, fromBit, toBit) {
  if (toBit === undefined) toBit = fromBit
  var maskSize = ee.Number(1).add(toBit).subtract(fromBit)
 var mask = ee.Number(1).leftShift(maskSize).subtract(1)
 return value.rightShift(fromBit).bitwiseAnd(mask)
 }

 var snow_cover =              cloud_free.map(function(img1)
              {
                 var ndsi = img1.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b04','sur_refl_b06']); 
                var evi1 = ndsi.expression('(thr>0.4) ? 1 : 0', 
                                           {  'thr' : ndsi  });
                 return evi1.clip(table).updateMask(img1.select('mask'));
              });


   var afterFilter = ee.Filter.lessThan({
   leftField: 'system:time_start',
   rightField: 'system:time_start'
   });

    var joined = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Join.saveAll('after').apply({
    primary: snow_cover,
    secondary: snow_cover,
    condition: afterFilter
     }));


     var sign = function(i, j) { // i and j are images
     return ee.Image(j).neq(i) // Zero case
     .multiply(ee.Image(j).subtract(i).clamp(-1, 1)).int();
     };

     var kendall = ee.ImageCollection(joined.map(function(current) {
     var afterCollection = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(current.get('after'));
       return afterCollection.map(function(image) {
        // The unmask is to prevent accumulation of masked pixels that
      // result from the undefined case of when either current or image
      // is masked.  It won't affect the sum, since it's unmasked to zero.
       return ee.Image(sign(current, image)).unmask(0);
      });
     // Set parallelScale to avoid User memory limit exceeded.
       }).flatten()).reduce('sum', 2);

      var palette = ['red', 'white', 'green'];
    // Stretch this as necessary.
     Map.addLayer(kendall, {palette: palette}, 'kendall');
     print(joined)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have lost the `system:time_start` property at the time you join `snow_cover` with itself. You can call `copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())` to add it back.

```
var cloud_free = dataset.map(
  function(img) {
    var qa = img.select('StateQA')
    var cloudState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 0, 1)
    var cloudShadowState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 2)
    var cirrusState = bitwiseExtract(qa, 8, 9)
    var mask = cloudState.eq(0) // Clear
      .and(cloudShadowState.eq(0)) // No cloud shadow
      .and(cirrusState.eq(0)) // No cirrus
    var maskedImage = img.updateMask(mask)
    return maskedImage.addBands(mask.rename('mask'))
      .copyProperties(img, img.propertyNames())
  })

var snow_cover = cloud_free.map(function(img1) {
  var ndsi = img1.normalizedDifference(['sur_refl_b04', 'sur_refl_b06'])
  var evi1 = ndsi.expression('(thr>0.4) ? 1 : 0', {
    'thr': ndsi
  })
  return evi1.clip(table).updateMask(img1.select('mask'))
    .copyProperties(img1, img1.propertyNames())
})
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f0b8f1bdc6c131476aedbeac886c7f6a

Comment: Thanks for this reply. Now its showing the image. But why its not showing the trend. Image have only zero value.

Comment: Please share your asset.

Comment: I have used this shape file name as table : https://code.earthengine.google.com/asset=users/rakeshsahu1609/Chandra_basin_projectedt

Comment: I have used this 
 assest as name table https://code.earthengine.google.com/asset=users/rakeshsahu1609/Chandra_basin_projectedt

Comment: You can use this link to import the my  asset

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting to see, but you do get something: https://code.earthengine.google.com/265c3030d5d231bcbc40a3de6b3eea5b